# How to Generate 2 Levels Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

If I have 2 variables

- A = 2
- B = 3

I want to generate result like this

```
A  |  B  |  Text

1  |  1  |  Text1
1  |  2  |  Text2
1  |  3  |  Text3
2  |  1  |  Text4
2  |  2  |  Text5
2  |  3  |  Text6
```

I try to Google and can achieved 1 level with this query

```
    declare @start int = 1
    declare @end  int = 3

    ;with numcte  
    AS  
    (  
      SELECT @start as [SEQUENCE]
      UNION all  
      SELECT [SEQUENCE] + 1
      FROM numcte WHERE [SEQUENCE] < @end 
    )      
    SELECT  [SEQUENCE], 'text' + CAST([SEQUENCE] as varchar) as [text] FROM numcte
```

How can I achieve 2 levels loop?

Comment: Use a cross join and row_number() for the 'text' part. (Though a recursive CTE isn't the most efficient way to generate numbers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One rather simple method is:

```
select a.a, b.b, concat('text', row_number() over (order by a, b))
from (values (1), (2)) a(a) cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3)) b(b);
```

Or if you really want to declare variables:

```
declare @a int = 2;
declare @b int = 3;
with n as (
      select 1 as n union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < @a or n < @b
    )
select na.n as a, nb.n as b, concat('text', row_number() over (order by na.n, nb.n))
from n na join
     n nb
     on na.n <= @a and nb.n <= @b;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b5844373c41ef30bad679b932d4c517) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Use a numbers table (many examples you can use by searching). One way to produce what is likely a vastly simplified example is:

```
with cte as (
   select 1 as num 
   union all select num + 1 from cte where num < 3 )
select cte.num, cte2.num from cte  
cross join cte as cte2 
where cte.num in (1, 2)
order by cte.num, cte2.num
;
```

Work through that - it may look daunting. Start thinking in terms of sets! [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=de54f054bc30bc8306f2dbab242d65ca)